# UIAccessbility reading same label two times when tapped

Tags: ios, xcode, uiaccessibility

I have a view  in storyboard and it has a label. I have enabled accessibility from "Identity Inspector" in Xcode. Problem is voiceover is reading the label text two times when tapped once. I don't have any code, its just simple label in storyboard.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Point [Accessibility Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/TestingAccessibilityOfiOSApps/TestAccessibilityonYourDevicewithVoiceOver/TestAccessibilityonYourDevicewithVoiceOver.html) at it and report back what you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a category in project that was returning UIAccessbility label. Removed it and worked.